# Relationship return Null [ Laravel ]

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

[image]

> Relationship return NULL `Shop`

i have 2 table `Expense` and `Shop`. Sometime i solved issue like this by set `foreign key` to it. And its doesnt work for this..

**My Shop Model**

```
<pre>
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
    }

    public function expense()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Expense::class, 'shop_id');
    }
</pre>
```

**My Expense Model**

```
<pre>
   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);  
    }

    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Expense::class, 'expense_id', 'shop_id');
    }
</pre>
```

Any Help? Thanks...

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: i screenshop my issue to question,  pls check it bro @AliFarhoudi

Comment: have you a shop_id field in your expenses table?

Comment: @dparoli yep....

Comment: Then you should add the code you use to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Expense` model's shop relation is pointing to an wrong model (Expense). It must be `Shop`

```
public function shop()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Shop::class, 'shop_id');
}
```

Comment: @CamBoKidz If you have a field shop_id field in the expenses table this answer is the right one, if you got null result you probably have some other issue that is not is not visible in the code you posted.

Comment: @CamBoKiDz Are you sure you have related records?